# Webbrowser not supported

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a simple WebBrowser control that navigates to the address https://cup.asl.brindisi.it/ncup/, but I receive an error message:
The browser used is not supported by the application.
I think it's because of the obsolete component, but how can I solve it? I use Visual Studio 10 with Framework 4.0, but I also tried Visual Studio 2019 and Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Can you provide more details? It's hard to guess what you're trying to do. Where this message is displayed?

Comment: This is probably due to a too old version of Internet Explorer being installed and the web application not supporting it. What version of IE is the WebBrowser control using? (Use [WebBrowser.Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.version?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_Version))

Comment: @rm.szc81  I'm not trying to do anything, I just want to view the page

Comment: @MindSwipe The Version is 11.0.18362.387 which corresponds to the version of Internet Explorer installed, but if I use Internet Explorer directly the page opens, so the problem is with the WebBrowser control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the [Browser Emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730%28v%3Dvs.85%29#browser-emulation). It is as simple as adding this one liner at the start of your program:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, 11000);
```

Comment: Thanks but I've tried all the solutions of this type and they don't work for me.

Comment: This solution should make the `WebBrowser` control to behave exactly like IE 11. I have used it in practice and it works.

Comment: If you want to do it, create a simple WebBrowser, make the change you wrote and then go to https://cup.asl.brindisi.it/ncup/. He continues to give me error.

Comment: I can navigate to [this page](https://cup.asl.brindisi.it/ncup/) without seeing any error message. The `Version` property of the control returns the value `11.0.17134.112`.

Comment: Now I'm really confused, my version, as written before, is 11.0.18362.387, superior to yours, yet I get the unsupported browser error.
I tried with VS 2010 professional and with VS 2019 professional with the same result. I don't understand, do you have any particular settings that I don't know?

Comment: I have Windows 10 (not updated to the latest version), Internet Explorer 11 version 11.112.17134.0, and Microsoft Edge version 42.17134.1.0. The Visual Studio is 2017, and the Framework 4.8.

Comment: Where do you enter the registry key change? I put it in the Load event.

Comment: I enter it before `Application.Run()`. But when you enter it once, there is no need to enter it again. Unless you change the name of the executable. Entering it multiple times causes no harm though.

Comment: Ok, entering the string before Application.Run works! Thank you very much for your patience.